# Magento - Meta description for sub-category

Tags: php, magento, categories

How can I get metaDesciption for subcategory (for main category works ok)? These don't work:

```
$category->load();
if ($title) {
  $headBlock->setTitle($title);
}
if ($description = $category->getMetaDescription()) {
   $headBlock->setDescription($description);
}
```

I tried many things but without success.

Comment: which category do you load in there?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
?>   

<p class="subcategory-meta-description">
    <?php echo $cur_category->getMetaDescription(); ?>
</p>
```